# Click (mousedown) event of a select element

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have an empty select element, I want to execute some code when that element is clicked on, but I do not want the dropdown list to appear, here is what I have found:

1. When I disabled the select element I cannot catch the mousedown event.
2. When I enable the select element I can capture the mousedown event but the dropdown list appears.

For arguements sake what I want is to be able to click the select element, JavaScript to throw an alert box but I want to prevent the dropdown list from displaying.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

capture `onmousedown` event of select element and cancel the event by setting `event.returnValue` to false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSelectMouseDown() {
        event.returnValue = false;
        alert("mouse down caught and cancelled");
    }
</script>

<select id="select" onmousedown="onSelectMouseDown();"></select>
```

Comment: Ok this is looking more promising, I will have a play around and return when I'm done :-)

Comment: After making sure I got my JavaScript events correct this worked like a charm! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to disable a select element and wrap the select element in a div (or something else) of the same height and width as the select element and use mousedown event with this div?

Comment: Hmmm... will that work as the select will have a higher z-index compared with the select? I will try now, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No this hasn't worked, like I thought the div being behind the disabled select box doesn't pickup the click event.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function makeDisable(){
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
    x.disabled=true
}
function makeEnable(){
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
    x.disabled=false
}
function f() {
makeDisable();
alert("something");
t=setTimeout("makeEnable();",1);
}
</script>

<select id="mySelect" onMouseDown="f();">
  <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```